# Obtaining users data after accepting / allowing a Chatter Application

Tags: rest-api, database, data, php

I'm slowly on the road to completing my PHP application, the final piece to my knowledge is figuring out how, after a user accepts the use of an Application (I think I'm using a remote app atm), to start logging their data under an administrative account?

So I have a Admin/Dev user set up, that connects through a remote app, as long as I auth under them I can log their data, I would assume that then I would need to log into EACH user each time I'm trying to log data? Is there a way to create a master account, sign users underneath it, have that data aggregated into the same database, and use the remote connect app to log/copy/archive all data that has happened between X time and X time?

Is there a way to bypass logging in as a user, to directly access the app and aggregate all data that happens underneath it? What is the best solution to this problem?

Thanks =)

Comment: What do you mean by 'log their data'? I think you need to look at the Force.com security model to figure this out - http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Overview_of_Force.com_Security - you should be able to give your admin user access to the other users' data.

Comment: I mean wall posts, chat messages, group messages, change history etcetra. Think of it as, you accept this app, we track everything you do on Chatter and put it in a database somewhere. Users are well aware of this and have to sign and accept this beforehand, so we aren't just doing it to be creepers.

Comment: I think then the answer is to have your app log in as an admin user with sufficient rights to see everything that you need. Managing all those user accounts is going to be problematic at best.

Comment: Yeah I'm already seeing that, I've set my app up to remotely log in as admin already, after that, does accepting the app add those users to some type of group or something that I can poll?

Comment: No - I don't think you can query anything to see who has accepted the app. But your app could use the API to insert a record somewhere to flag the new user.